# How do I create a default dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: string, python-3.x, dictionary, nested, defaultdict

I am trying to write some code that involves creating a default dictionary of dictionaries. However, I have no idea how to initialise/create such a thing. My current attempt looks something like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
inner_dict = {}
dict_of_dicts = defaultdict(inner_dict(int))
```

The use of this default dict of dictionaries is to for each pair of words that I produce from a file I open (e.g. [['M UH M', 'm oo m']] ), to set each segment of the first word delimited by empty space as a key in the outer dictionary, and then for each segment in the second word delimited by empty space count the frequency of that segment.

For example

```
[['M UH M', 'm oo m']] 
(<class 'dict'>, {'M': {'m': 2}, 'UH': {'oo': 1}})
```

Having just run this now it doesn't seem to have output any errors, however I was just wondering if something like this will actually produce a default dictionary of dictionaries.

Apologies if this is a duplicate, however previous answers to these questions have been confusing and in a different context.

Comment: Well, your current code as pasted is invalid ... `inner_dict` is defined to be a dictionary and then you try to call it as `inner_dict(int)` ...

Answer (score 2):

To initialise a `defaultdict` that creates dictionaries as its default value you would use:

```
d = defaultdict(dict)
```

For this particular problem, a `collections.Counter` would be more suitable

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict, Counter
>>> d = defaultdict(Counter)
>>> for a, b in zip(*[x.split() for x in ['M UH M', 'm oo m']]):
...    d[a][b] += 1
>>> print(d)
defaultdict(collections.Counter,
            {'M': Counter({'m': 2}), 'UH': Counter({'oo': 1})})
```

**Edit**

You expressed interest in a comment about the equivalent without a `Counter`.  Here is the equivalent using a plain `dict`

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(dict)
>>> for a, b in zip(*[x.split() for x in ['M UH M', 'm oo m']]):
...    d[a][b] = d[a].get(b, 0) + 1
>>> print(d)
defaultdict(dict, {'M': {'m': 2}, 'UH': {'oo': 1}})
```

Comment: That is an elegant way! Is there any way of doing that without Counter, but instead just default dictionaries and dictionaries?

Comment: @IndifferentPotato I've added the equivalent using a `defaultdict(dict)`

Comment: The equivalent with just plain **dict** outputs an AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split''. :/

Comment: @IndifferentPotato Only if the code you entered is not what's in the answer.  Check what you've typed.

Answer (score 0):

You also could a use a normal dictionary and its `setdefault` method.

`my_dict.setdefault(key, default)` will look up `my_dict[key]` and ...

- ... if the key already exists, return its current value without modifying it, or ...
- ... assign the default value (`my_dict[key] = default`) and then return that.

So you can call `my_dict.setdefault(key, {})` always when you want to get a value from your outer dictionary instead of the normal `my_dict[key]` to retrieve either the real value assigned with this key if it#s present, or to get a new empty dictionary as default value which gets automatically stored into your outer dictionary as well.

Example:

```
outer_dict = {"M": {"m": 2}}

inner_dict = d.setdefault("UH", {})
# outer_dict = {"M": {"m": 2}, "UH": {}}
# inner_dict = {}
inner_dict["oo"] = 1
# outer_dict = {"M": {"m": 2}, "UH": {"oo": 1}}
# inner_dict = {"oo": 1}

inner_dict = d.setdefault("UH", {})
# outer_dict = {"M": {"m": 2}, "UH": {"oo": 1}}
# inner_dict = {"oo": 1}
inner_dict["xy"] = 3
# outer_dict = {"M": {"m": 2}, "UH": {"oo": 1, "xy": 3}}
# inner_dict = {"oo": 1, "xy": 3}
```

This way you always get a valid `inner_dict`, either an empty default one or the one that's already present for the given key. As dictionaries are mutable data types, modifying the returned `inner_dict` will also modify the dictionary inside `outer_dict`.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers propose alternative solutions or show you can make a default dictionary of dictionaries using `d = defaultdict(dict)`

but the question asked how to make a default dictionary of **default dictionaries**, my navie first attempt was this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
my_dict = defaultdict(defaultdict(list))
```

however this throw an error: `*** TypeError: first argument must be callable or None`

so my second attempt which works is to make a callable using the lambda key word to make an anonymous function:

```
from collections import defaultdict
my_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
```

which is more concise than the alternative method using a regular function:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def default_dict_maker():
    return defaultdict(list)
my_dict = defaultdict(default_dict_maker)
```

you can check it works by assigning:

```
my_dict[2][3] = 5
my_dict[2][3]
>>> 5
```

or by trying to return a value:

```
my_dict[0][0]
>>> []
my_dict[5]
>>> defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {})
```

## tl;dr

this is your oneline answer `my_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))`